# Replace part of a file name in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, command

I have a file name in Linux that is something like:

```
out-06307963554982-8091-20220726-121922-1658834362.208826.wav
```

I need to replace the first number in bash with X's and struggling to find the right solution. The number can vary in size but the 'out' will always remain the same.

Final file name should look like

```
out-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-8091-20220726-121922-1658834362.208826.wav
```

OR alternatively we can cut everything in front of the second -

```
20220726-121922-1658834362.208826.wav
```

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="out-06307963554982-8091-20220726-121922-1658834362.208826.wav"
echo "ORIGINAL=$filename"

IFS='-' read -r -a fields <<< "$filename"
new_second_field=$( echo "${fields[1]}" | tr '[:digit:]' 'X' )
fields[1]="$new_second_field"
new_filename=$(echo "${fields[@]}" | tr ' ' '-')

echo "NEW======$new_filename"

####################################################

# Cut everything in front of the second '-'

echo "$filename" | cut -d'-' -f4-
```

- `IFS='-' read -r -a fields <<< "$filename"`: splits the filename into an array where each item is text, split on `-`.
- then `tr` is used to replace each digit in the second field by an `X`.  This ensure that the number of `X` == number of digits.
- the second field is replaced by the new value consisting only of `X`s.
- the new filename is "rebuilt" by doing an `echo` of the fields array, replacing all spaces by `-`.

For your alternative method, simply `cut` everything on `-` and display the results from the 4th item on (`-f4-`).

The output of this script is:

```
ORIGINAL=out-06307963554982-8091-20220726-121922-1658834362.208826.wav
NEW======out-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-8091-20220726-121922-1658834362.208826.wav
20220726-121922-1658834362.208826.wav
```